# Can I change the default sort order for searches in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

For a long time my outlook search results were sorting by "importance" by default and every time I would have to manually change it to sort by date. Eventually it stayed sorting by date, but I did one search where I arranged by file size and now it is stuck on that for all my searches.

Is there a way to set the default? If not, can someone explain the behavior that causes Outlook to choose a certain one as the default?

Comment: If you're going to downvote please let me know what I should add to improve the question

Comment: How exactly did you search?

Comment: At the top of the Outlook window there is a search bar, I type the query in there and hit enter. This is the only way I'm aware of

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following test:

Click the search bar > type some words to search > click the filter to By Size > clear the "X" on the left of search bar to exit search > click the search bar to search.

I found that the default filter is still By date. So i think that the default filter cannot be changed by yourself. It's suggested that you could exit your Outlook and restart to search again to check if there're any differences.

If the issue persists, please try to reset view to check if the problem is gone.

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.